# Lua: Table as tree of keys of another table

Tags: lua

I realy need something like this, but can't find over internet how to do it. I have table of values and first of them should turn into a key of another table, but second value should be key of previous value and so on. If hardcoded it would look like this:

```
tab["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]...["keyn-1"]["keyn"] = "value"
```

However I have dynamic table of keys and I don't know how it will look like when i want instert this tree of keys. I want solution that will let me add new branches in the middle of the tree, like:

```
tab["key1"]["key2"] = 123
tab["key1"]["key3"] = 234
print(tab.key1.key2) ---> 123
print(tab.key1.key3) ---> 234
```

**Example to solve:**

What I have:

```
tab1 = {"town", "home", 1, "cake"}
value = 1.032
tab2 = {}
```

What I want:

```
print(tab2.town.home.1.cake) ---> 1.032
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local function read_nested_keys(tbl, keys)
   for _, k in ipairs(keys) do
      tbl = tbl[k]
      if tbl == nil then
         break
      end
   end
   return tbl
end

local function write_nested_keys(value, tbl, keys)
   local prev_tbl, last_k
   for _, k in ipairs(keys) do
      last_k, prev_tbl, tbl = k, tbl, tbl[k]
      if tbl == nil then
         tbl = {}
         prev_tbl[k] = tbl
      end
   end
   prev_tbl[last_k] = value
end
```

Example:

```
local keys = {"town", "home", 1, "cake"}
local value = 1.032
local root = {}

print(read_nested_keys(root, keys)) ---> nil

write_nested_keys(value, root, keys)

print(root.town.home[1].cake)       ---> 1.032
print(read_nested_keys(root, keys)) ---> 1.032
```